# Disabled Radio Button Not Dithered

Tags: html

I have an odd situation where I am disabling one radio button in a group of 4 but it doesn't look like it is disabled.  You can't click on it, so it is truly disabled...but it looks just like all the others.

This is only happening in one environment I am working in...and due to the situation I don't even know exactly what the differences are except one is Unix and one is Linux.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It seems like the browsers are just rendering the radio differently. There's not much you can do about that, besides changing the CSS for the disabled radio.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your systems are using the same browser, one of your systems may have a different color depth. For example, one my only be 8-bit 256 colors and the other may be 24-bit millions of colors. This might explain the "dithering" part of the title. UNIX systems use X11 where it is still more common to see a 256 color display by default. Make both systems the same color depth and see if that fixes it.

It is also possible that the CSS for disabling the radio button is using an opacity setting and it can't "ghost" the radio box on one display for some reason (color depth may be one, card limitations, etc.). Having an entirely different image for the disabled radio button would be better in this case because it would not rely on being able to do what is called "alpha blending".

Keep in mind, we have no more details, so some of what I said may not apply. I just hope something here might help. If you have screenshots and details, we can narrow an answer better.

Comment: I'm not really using a browser, it is a window within an application that displays the html.  From what I know, this application is the same in both environments.  Thanks for your comments though, I am going to check into some of those.

Comment: Cool. I hope it helps!